# Debugging the C# TBBs

Tags: 2011

This is my first time when i do not have access of the dev CDA server so i want to configure the C# TBB solution at my local machine.I have below question in my head -

1- Is it possible to debug any TBB at my local machine rather than at Tridion CMS server ?

2-  Is it possible to upload the this DLL in the CMS from my local machine ?

I am a bit sure that both things are possible but would like to be sure before passing these word to my client.

Note- Offcourse in case 2 we will require the user account detail of CMS server.

**UPDATE-** 
After reading the valuable answers by Chris and Pankaj, I feel Update about server information in this question.
So basically we are using java along with Tridion and both CMS and CDA servers are Linux based servers having apache as webserver. But in local machine we are using Microsoft windows 7 and IIS.
 Would there be any challenge to do the below suggested configuration for C# TBB?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are using a C# Fragment TBB or uploading a .NET Assembly as you TBB

Comment: Thanks Chris, we are using both C# fragment and .NET Assembly in the project. at the moment i am concerning about the uploading a .NET Assembly.

Comment: The CMS side of Tridion cannot run on Linux / Apache, it always requires Windows + IIS.

Comment: @user584 regarding your update, a C# TBB is a C# TBB, regardless of where it was built or where it will be used (as long as it was build against the correct assemblies, i.e. same version as those in your CMS). Technically you can build a C# TBB using the Mono C# compiler and that will be usable just like if you would compile it in Visual Studio. btw. as Quirijn already indicated, your CMS server is running on Windows & IIS, but that is besides the point.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is really yes and yes.

1. To debug from your local machine you will need to set up remote
   debugging on your server  (see http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_D76A55C77B39455C88BA8159131156AC)
2. You can either upload your DLL using the
   CME interface or use the upload `TCMUploadAssembly.exe` which comes with
   Tridion (this can be configured as a build event from your local
   machine in Visual Studio if you like to work that way (see http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_62DF7C10DF8C4690B977CD7D53124D97).

Both links above require an SDL login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris , I updated the question with server information. Would you give me your suggestion in this particular mix enviroment.

Comment: I see your update, but I fear there is a mistake. The CMS server can only be a Windows machine running IIS. Could you validate your setup. Have you tried installing Remote Debugging and the Upload Tool.

Comment: Yes Chris,we are using windows & IIS at CMS server.Though i have not tried it up to now and planing to do so.

Comment: Is there dependency on any Tridion component/service which we require to install at my local machine to debug the C# TBB remotely ?  also what is this " Remote Debugging and the Upload Tool" which i need at the CMS server ? Please explore the point

Answer (score 1):

Yes both of them are possible but certainly not OOTB.

- For debugging TBB at your local machine you need to install the MS- Remote Debugger tool on the Server and you may want to follow this link [Remote Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx) - Just note the Remote Debugger Tool that you have to use should be compatible with .NET framework and VS you are using and further the tool is a bit buggy, so you may need to put a lots of patience to get it work.
- For upload the C# TBB from local machine, you need to access the TCM Upload Assembly executable, and you can search for a multiple ways to execute depending on what kind of access you will have to access the CMS server from your local machine. 
  If you have all the right access, you can write a post-build event in for your project in the Visual Studio, which will eventually execute the same command that you generally put to upload in the command prompt on the CMS server.

Comment: Curiosity question: how would you envision something like this to work OOTB?

Comment: I never understood why people use a post-build event for this. Don't these people ever compile?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pankaj, I updated the question with server information. Would you give me your suggestion in this particular mix enviroment.

Comment: @Nuno: May be something as follow: 1) For uploading TBB from remote machine, an addition in Tools menu in CME just like Template Builder - may be we can call it as Template Uploader - initial installing and configuration will take care of all the complexity of uploading the TBB.
2) For Remote debugging we can (with Due warnings regarding Security) install the remote debugger with CME itself.

Comment: @DominicCronin: Completely agree with your concerns. Post Build event just for abstracting people from the complexity (for those who do not know much about or are new to Tridion and .NET), as the process is only related to specific users, they can choose whatever different ways are there - 1) Batch File execution 2) Direct Command Line execution 3) Keeping Post Build Events commented and then un-commenting whenever they want to deploy.

Comment: @DominicCronin sure I compile when I'm done coding and when that is successful I want my TBBs uploaded in the CMS, so a post build step is perfect for that job. But that indeed only works when I'm the only developer, when working in a team, then instead of the post build a Upload Assemblies Add-In like this (http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/AssemblyUploader2.aspx) makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to top of what Chris and Gaur described

1 - As c# assembly and debug file reside on the CMS server. you need remote access of that machine to login in and setup up remote debugger etc.

2 - You can open the CMS interface in your browser and upload the c# tbb, but with this you would not be able to upload .pdb, which is required to debug.

Comment: It might be possible to allow Tridion to load the tbb modules without symbols and then add them from another location. I've never tried it, because uploading the symbols with the tbb works fine.

Comment: right - that seems also possible using Visual studio features. Thanks.